# @Procedure annotation orphaning database connections (spring-data-jpa)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We have a batch job in production that calls a stored procedure to update some tables. This stored proc does not return anything. Right now, we are running out of database connections as 1 connection gets orphaned every time the job is ran. The repository uses the Spring Data CrudRepository with the procedure annotation.

Are we missing something in regards to the call and spring data jpa? Thanks in advance!

```
@Repository
public interface CertificationRepository extends CrudRepository<Certification,     Integer> {
    @Procedure("usp_batch_update_certifications")
    void updateCertifications(Date previousFireTime);
}
```

Comment: I created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-663 to investigate this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which Spring-Data-JPA Version and which PersistenceProvider are you using?
Could you point me to a reduced example app that reproduces the problem?

As said in the comments I could reproduce your problem.
The procedure execution requires a TX which is either not present or the surrounding TX is never committed.

You could try adding the procedure method with `@Transactional`

The Role entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureParameter;

/**
 * Oracle PL/SQL
 *
 * <pre>
 *  CREATE or replace PROCEDURE update_roles (pattern_i IN varchar) AS
 *  BEGIN 
 *    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('update_roles Received pattern: ' || pattern_i);
 *  END;
 * /
 * 
 * <pre>
 */
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Role.updateRoles"
                         , procedureName = "update_roles"
                         , parameters = { 
                            @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "pattern"
                                                    , mode = ParameterMode.IN
                                                    , type = String.class) })
})
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id @GeneratedValue//
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    ...
```

The RoleRepository:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Serializable> {

    @Procedure
    @Transactional
    void updateRoles(@Param("pattern") String pattern);
}
```

Comment: I could reproduce the problem in a small sample app. It seems that the TX in which context the procedure is invoked doesn't commit.

Comment: A simple fix you could try is to manually mark the updateCertifications(..) method with @Transactional.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas! I had tried adding the transactional annotation up at the service layer. Adding it on the repository like you suggested has cleared the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Finally I got this solution. Thank you.